# Unable to connect to REST service java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://jira.xyz.abc.com/rest/api/2/search?jql

Tags: jenkins, jira

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins to Jira to have a Jenkins push the Console log into JIRA Issue as a `Comment`.

I have installed `Jira Issue Updater` and configured the plugin in Jenkins.

Using the rest endpoint, I'm able to push a comment into JIRA via `SOAPUI`, however the Jira Issue updater always throws below error

```
-------------------------------------------------------
JIRA Update Results Recorder
-------------------------------------------------------
Unable to connect to REST service
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://jira.xyz.abc.com/rest/api/2/search?jqlBuild step 'JIRA Issue Results Updater' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help if any pointers.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the configuration done "Jira Issue Updater" on Jenkins, so we could have better context on the error thrown

Comment: that url is not for updating issues, you need to call PUT on a specific issue: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis-6848604/